# My Base Class is Changing every time in my code. How I can overcome this?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have had the below question asked in interview, i'm curious to learn the answer.

I have a base class, 'GeneratorBaseClass' that is extended by Generator. The question I was asked was about creating a new base class 'GeneratorBaseClass2' and having Generator change to extend that at run time (without having to change Generator). So, as an example of the code

```
public class GeneratorBase1 {
    public GeneratorBase1(){
        System.out.println("Generator Base 1 is used");
    }
}

public class Generator  extends  GeneratorBase1{

    public Generator() {
        //will call the appropriate super class
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Generator test=new Generator();


    }


}
```

And I want to have Generator pick up a new GeneratorBase at run time, so change to

```
public class GeneratorBase2 {
    public GeneratorBase2(){
        System.out.println("Generator Base 2 is used");
    }
}
```

The form of Generator can be changed, but must not be changed every time the base class changes. This is about allowing the selection of base class at runtime and I don't want to just change the "extends ...." portion

Comment: Do you seriously believe it can be done at run time ? The need of changing the inheritance at run time is a case of bad design !!!

Comment: Stop changing your class name then...

Comment: you cannot do this in java at runtime. I am not downvoter here.

Comment: why is he getting the downvotes? that was a question, it can be answered. explain it please

Comment: Why would someone design it that way? What ist the point in extending different classes each time? If the base class to be used share the same interface you could make your own a generic one and add the interface constraint.

Comment: @Aakeef *Sigh*, you post this question, it gets closed as being unclear, you post the identical question again. Consider rewriting it so its clearer. For example stop saying T1 and T2, say what the T classes are/do. Post a source code of T1 and generator THAT COMPILES and then say what you want to change. As I've said before this is impossible, you can't have generator extends an old class and have it "decide for itself" that it needs to stop extending the old class and start extending  a new class. I think you've misinterpreted the interviewers question

Comment: @Manuel The repeating of a question that was unclear (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317997/my-base-class-is-changing-every-time-in-my-code-how-to-make-it-stable-that-i) and the bare minimum non compiling code that if anything makes things more confusing

Answer (score 5):

I am trying my best shot here. The question is ambigous though. Why would someone want to change the base class again and again ? This might be because the functionality that the base class is providing is changing at run-time. If this is the case there are two possible cases.

1. The base class should be an interface and nothing more.
2. You should composite the changing functionality in the base class and let the implementation change at run-time like the way your Strategy design pattern works.

Comment: +1 for suggesting strategy pattern

Comment: Can i do this, whatever changes done in new Base Class('T2'),
i will do that changes in Old Base Class('T1') only.
So that i should not make any changes in Existing Code..

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonably way to go about things. But as I understand it Aakeef wants to not change generator and have it pick up a new T class without telling it. T classes changing for version control purposes

Comment: @Richtea : Than he can re-load the base class from a remote location using a class loader OR may be the question was about Dynamic loading of his "generator" class itself.

Comment: @Geek Presumably that would require all the (potentially loadable) base classes to have the same name. i.e. be com.test.T and com.test2.T

Comment: @Geek if i kept my base class as a Interface, i can add interface those class which i know,means

public class Generator  implements  GeneratorBase1,GeneratorBase2 {
    public Generator() {
        //will call the appropriate super class
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Generator test=new Generator();
    }
}

If new base class GeneratorBase3 {--} has come into picture i need to Change my code as a 
public class Generator  implements  GeneratorBase1,GeneratorBase2,GeneratorBase3 {-----
}

Comment: @Aakeef : Yes, if you say so. Which means you will have to have a new class ready with implements GB1,GB2,GB3 and then you have to unload the older class and load this new class for your application to run with the new code. How you decide I have a new class to load is unclear to me. Also like I mentioned this looks more of a strategy pattern question than anything else. I could be wrong but may be you didn't understand the question correctly.